# PHP search MySQL table

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

I've built this little script that searches a table in my database, but for the life of me I can't seem to find anywhere on how to display the table information if someone only searches for the email. I want to be able to search for only the email and have it display all the information for that email address from the database. Any thoughts?

```
<?php
$profile = $_POST["profile"];

mysql_connect ("", "", "");
mysql_select_db ("");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email`='$email' and `about`='$about' and 
`age`='$age' and `sex`='$sex' and `website`='$website'";


$result = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result) {
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo $row[0],$row[1],$row[2];
}
}else{

}
?>

<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-numeric field must be enclosed with single quotes in a query.

```
<?php  

  $search = $_POST["search"];
  mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") OR die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db ("your_db_name") or die(mysql_error());

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email`='$search'";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

  if($result) 
   {    
      while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))   
       {      
          echo $row[0],$row[1],$row[2];   
       }    
     }
   else
     { 
       echo "No result";  
     }
 ?>

<form action="profile.php" method="post">  
  <input type="text" name="search"><br>  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

EDIT:

In above code-snippet you have single `text` field and a `submit button` so you can use `"search"` field value to search on any one database field at a time.

If you want to search on email then sql query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email`='$search'";
```

You can use `OR` operator to search on one or more field:

```
 SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email`='$search' or about`='$search'";
```

You can use LIKE operator to search a string

```
SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email` LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Comment: Will this display the result or is it the best way the get the $query?

Comment: @Pxlc - Yes! it will display the result. See I've edit my post.

Comment: Are you sure that works? It's not working on my end, try example@example.com http://arnid.us/profile.php

Comment: @Pxlc - Please post the code in the opening post that you have in given link.

Comment: I'm still not seeing any results. I'm using Heroku as a host, but that shouldn't cause any backend problems. I replaced the original SELECT with SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `email`='$profile'";

Comment: @Pxlc - Have a look at edited post. There is a problem with $_POST["profile"] because "profile" isn't in request collection. Use $_POST["search"].

Comment: It worked :) Is there any way to make the results display in HTML rather than echo. Could I just do <p>$row[0]</p> ?

Comment: @Pxlc - Yes, you can write html tags too along with result. echo "<p>$row[0]</p>";

Comment: Okay, awesome thanks dude :) Out of curiosity, could http://arnid.us/profile.php?search=example@example.com display results as well?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is write another query

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE email='$email'";
```